# не получается задать цвет роли, которую я создаю через команду Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

и так. У меня есть команда !create_role имя новой роли , цвет роли
вот код :

```
async def create_role(ctx, *, name, color):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name = name, colour=discord.Colour(color))
    ctx.send(f'роль {name} успешно создана')
```

при написании этой команды в дискорд: !create_role lalala #FFFFFF

[image: здесь показана ошибка в коносли]

что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то вот так должно работать:

```
async def create_role(ctx, name, color):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_role(name = name, color=discord.Color(color))
    ctx.send(f'Роль {name} успешно создана!')
```

Comment: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead.
вот ошибка которая выводится с помощью вашего варианта